# how to sign in linkedin sending access token to server side

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm using these links [link1](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth), [link2](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth) to sign in through linked in my android app.I've also created my app on linkedin developer and also provided links for oauth 2.0 and javascript. by running code in the link2:

```
 final Activity thisActivity = this;

    findViewById(R.id.btnLiSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(thisActivity, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthSuccess() {
                    // Authentication was successful.  You can now do
                    // other calls with the SDK.
                    Log.d(TAG, "success" + LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success" + LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                    // Handle authentication errors
                    Log.d(TAG, "failed " + error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, true);
        }
    });
```

I'm getting login and getting an access token. I want to send an access token to my website server and get user data from my website. when I'm sending this token it is not working. do I have to get some other token. please guide step by step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it. From the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth):

> Mobile vs. server-side access tokens
>
> It is important to note that access tokens that are acquired via the
>   Mobile SDK are only useable with the Mobile SDK, and cannot be used to
>   make server-side REST API calls.
>
> Similarly, access tokens that you already have stored from your users
>   that authenticated using a server-side REST API call will not work
>   with the Mobile SDK.

Instead get the required info on the device and send the info to your server.

Comment: Sending the info to server can be impersonated without any backend verification

Comment: @Shadow you are right. The SDK, in the current form, does not do a good job for signing in/creating account. It's more suitable for importing profile data for existing users.